# What becomes of conservation of energy in many-worlds theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, quantum-interpretations, superposition

Disclaimer, my interest in physics is purely recreational; also, in spite of my research so far, I couldn't really make sense of the question I am asking here.

What follows is my understanding so far, please correct me if I'm wrong...

The Copenhagen interpretation states that each time a measurement is made, the state vector (wave function) of the system under scrutiny collapses to one particular state, and that prior to this, the state vector is the sum of all possible states prior to this measurement. In other words (?), a superposition of states.

In the many-worlds interpretation, it is said that when this collapsing occurs, in fact, all possible states occur in a different world.

And this is where I have trouble, because to my eyes, this is a direct contradiction with the principle of conservation of energy. If the many-worlds hypothesis is true, it would mean, to my eyes, that the energy after the measurement of a particular system is n times that of the system before, where n is the number of possible states. And even though this energy is distributed among these n worlds, there are still n-1 times the energy unaccounted for. Created, in fact.

How do many-world theories counter this (probably naive) argument of mine?

Comment: Regarding superposition, see decohence/diagonalization of density matrix.

Comment: @innisfree do you mean this as a means to further my understanding of it, or as a clue to the answer?

Comment: Each branch of the wavefunction is 'smaller' in that its norm is less than one. So the energy is just split up, not increased.

Comment: There's a theorem that says the angles of a triangle add to $\pi$.  What becomes of that theorem if you draw two triangles?

Comment: @knzhou but then how is energy conserved in the event of a measurement? Is it the measuring apparatus that takes the energy "away", so to speak?

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a time independent observable, then we have:

$$\frac{d\left<X\right>}{dt}= \frac{1}{i h}\left<\left[X,H\right]\right>\tag{1}$$

This means that the expectation value of a time-independent Hamiltonian is conserved. In the context of the MWI, this then means that the average of the expectation value of the Hamiltonian across the branches where each branch gets a weight according to its probability, is the same as what it was in the initial state. So, you have to average the energy over the branches, not sum over them to get to the conserved energy.

One can then ask how it's possible that the entire universe with all its energy content gets duplicated due to a simple quantum measurement. But that's a problem for particular ideas where you assume that the different worlds exist side by side in some sense such that combining physical quantities in the different worlds would make sense. The pragmatic way forward is to stick to the physics and let the physics be the guide to what is a viable way of interpreting parallel words in the MWI.

Now, the whole point of the MWI is that a fundamental collapse of the wavefunction is incompatible with unitary time evolution of closed quantum systems. Physically, it shouldn't matter if our entire observable universe is part of a huge closed universe, but QM in that huge closed universe would not be unitary. And without unitary time evolution in a closed system you don't even get to Eq. (1).

If we then continue along the line of guiding ourselves what is physically reasonable instead of being ideological about sticking to philosophical ideas, then we're led to the MWI but we should not consider the different worlds as having a physical connection to each other; we're not talking about copies of our universe located inside a larger universe such that you could exchange matter and energy from one to the other. If that were the case then the sum of the energies from the different worlds would have a physical meaning. But there is nothing in the physics that would suggest such a thing is possible, it's purely an artifact of a mental picture where you imagine the different worlds side by side.